# Math.random doesnt work

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner am reading a JavaScript book. It contains this code, which does not work:

```js
var min = 5;
var max = 10;

alert( min + Math.random() * ( max ‐ min ) );
```

It is supposed to get a random number between min and max, but it doesnt work. Why not?

Comment: `Math.random(min, max)` gives a random number between `min` and `max`. What you provided is just some equation that uses `Math.random()`.

Comment: `"SyntaxError: illegal character` in the console

Comment: Thanks , there is just a wrong minus sign ))

Answer (score 2):

You have a wrong minus `‐` sign.

```js
var min = 5;
var max = 10;

alert(min + Math.random() * (max - min));
```

Answer (score 1):

'‐' in your code is illegal, it works if you change it to correct minus sign

```js
var min = 5;
var max = 10;

alert( min + Math.floor(Math.random()*(max - min)));
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this you have used wrong diffrence sign in your code so that error pops up use this:

```
var min = 5;
var max = 10;
alert( min + Math.random() *(max-min ) );
```